# Python: how import excel file from the web?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to import excel file from the link. I tried to do it with

```
filedlurl = 'https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/48d3ac/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/exchange-ee-connections_2021_daily.xls'
    
df = pd.read_excel(filedlurl, skiprows=2)
```

But the error was `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Exchange'`

then I found the following way from
[using Pandas to read in excel file from URL - XLRDError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243121/using-pandas-to-read-in-excel-file-from-url-xlrderror)

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/48d3ac/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/exchange-ee-connections_2021_daily.xls',
                 #sep='\t',
                 #parse_dates=[0],
                 names=['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
                skiprows=2)
df
```

Here is also a strange output.
How can I get the following table as when manually download from the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file isn't a CSV or an Excel file. Actual contents are an HTML table (see as follows).

```
Exchange in {0}, Import(+)/Export(-)
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">Exchange EE connections in MWh, MW</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td colspan="5">Data was last updated 06-01-2021</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td></td><td style="text-align:center;">EE net exchange</td><td style="text-align:center;">EE - FI</td><td style="text-align:center;">EE - LV</td><td style="text-align:center;">EE - RU</td>
                </tr>
            </thead><tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">01-01-2021</td><td style="text-align:right;">14575</td><td style="text-align:right;">20969,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">-4884,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">-1510,0</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">02-01-2021</td><td style="text-align:right;">12073</td><td style="text-align:right;">22479,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">-8001,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">-2405,0</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">03-01-2021</td><td style="text-align:right;">14321</td><td style="text-align:right;">22540,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">-8259,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">40,0</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">04-01-2021</td><td style="text-align:right;">14662</td><td style="text-align:right;">17653,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">-5829,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">2838,0</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">05-01-2021</td><td style="text-align:right;">13570</td><td style="text-align:right;">13779,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">-5314,0</td><td style="text-align:right;">5105,0</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td style="text-align:left;">06-01-2021</td><td style="text-align:right;">6243</td><td style="text-align:right;"></td><td style="text-align:right;"></td><td style="text-align:right;"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Use `pd.read_html` like so:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/48d3ac/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/exchange-ee-connections_2021_daily.xls'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]
```

That you can open your file in Excel is because Excel iterates through possible formats until finding something that works. Eg you can make a tab separated values (which should have extension .tsv) file, append .xls and while it isn't an actual horrible spread sheet format (XLS), Excel will still open it normally. It also does this with HTML data.

Answer (score 1):

First, can download the file using Python this way, using [urllib.request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961068/8565438):

```
import urllib.request
url='https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/48d3ac/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/exchange-ee-connections_2021_daily.xls'
filename='yourfile.csv'
urllib.request.urlretrieve (url,filename)
```

Then read it in using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Which will give you:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Exchange'
```

After checking with a real Excel, I find:

[image]

So something is wrong with your file, I suspect. With a correct file, the above method should work.

Comment: Yes, it always starts with this view, but if you press yes, the excel will open

Comment: That means it probably isn't an actual Excel file; Excel iterates through possible formats until seeing whether it works. Eg you can make a tab separated values (which should have extension `.tsv`) file, append `.xls` and while it isn't an actual horrible spread sheet format (XLS), Excel will still open it normally. Try opening the file in a text editor to see actual internal representation.

Answer (score 1):

Latest pandas (pandas==1.2.0) is able to read from url using `pd.read_excel` when `requests` is installed.

```
import pandas
url = "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/48d3ac/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/exchange-ee-connections_2021_daily.xls"
df = pandas.read_excel(url)
```

But your file seems corrupted, it triggers:

```
ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file
```