# Pandas read sharepoint excel file: XLRDError

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read a sharepoint excel file into a dataframe.
However I am getting error `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n<!DOCT'`

The question is similar to this: [using Pandas to read in excel file from URL - XLRDError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243121/using-pandas-to-read-in-excel-file-from-url-xlrderror) however my error is different based on this part `b'\r\n<!DOCT'`

I am not sure what this error even is - any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import pandas as pd
import io


url = 'url'
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
 ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
 web = ctx.web
 ctx.load(web)
 ctx.execute_query()
 print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj)
print(df)
```

**What i've tried**

`df = pd.read_csv(bytes_file_obj, error_bad_lines=False)`

However it just gives my data into 1 column, looks like html/JSON format.

The reason I put `error_bad_lines` in is because `read_csv` was giving me `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 5`