# wget command in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

Can someone explain me what is this problem? I downloaded wget on windows and I tried to show a table in jupyter notebook but I have this error, although when I go on this page, this file downloads. What is the problem? Thank you in advance! [image]

Comment: Did you check if the file is actually downloaded? `No such file or directory` error tells that the file you are trying to read is not found.

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj I thought !wget command shouldn't download this file on my computer. I thought it just should copy this table from site to notebook. But what I should to do to solve it, because this file hadn't download.

Comment: Try to read the file in as csv?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243121/using-pandas-to-read-in-excel-file-from-url-xlrderror

Comment: @prostak The answer in this superuser post should be useful. https://superuser.com/a/470706/1189221

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj But that is about linux.

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj Ou, I have this files on the homepage of jupyter notebook, but anyway I can't read it

Comment: Try specifying the complete path of the file in the `read_excel` function.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: If you want to read the table without downloading the file. `pandas.read_excel` can take as its first argument accept a valid `http`, `https` or `s3` URL as well

Comment: Can you run the `wget` command without the `-q` flag? This way, we can see what the `wget` command's output is.

Comment: Then I get the error "'https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysxs5srafoyxknb/_data_3_course.xlsx?dl=1': Scheme missing."

Comment: These files are in my computer's directory, but they have weight 0 bytes and I don't know why.

Comment: Thank you. Problem is solved)

Comment: Can you post the resolution as an answer? Was it the apostrophe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first order you need to write -q + "url", and then you need to write -O + "name. I mean just swap them like: !wget -q "url" -O "name"